# DockPanel ImageOption.Image is not showing the image

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-controls

I'll make it short,

My problem is: The image that i want to set in my `DockPanel` as icon is not showing.

Here is my Code

```
DockPanel dock = new DockPanel();
dock.ImageOption.Image = <Bitmap image here>; //
dock.Controls.Add(UserControl1);
UserControl1.MyDockPanel = dock;
```

Any expert opionion here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add image to DockPanel in the cs like this:

```
        DockPanel dock = new DockPanel();
        BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        myBitmapImage.BeginInit();
        myBitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri("...\\ico_48.ico", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        myBitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 2048;
        myBitmapImage.EndInit();

        Image image = new Image();
        image.Source = myBitmapImage;
        dock.Children.Add(image);

        Content = dock;
```